expo run:ios failing from new project
I am creating a fresh new expo project with npx create-expo-app@latest however, when running npx expo run:ios after npx expo prebuild -p ios the build is failing.
I am using;

"expo": "~51.0.35",
"react-native": "0.74.5",
MacOS Sequoia 15.0
Xcode 16.0

The xcodebuild.log is returning almost 3000 lines so I've attached the foot notes from the log.
Is there anything I should look for in particular within the logs?

note: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images'
will be run during every build because the option to run the script
phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target
'decidoapp' from project 'decidoapp') note: Run script build phase
'[Expo] Configure project' will be run during every build because the
option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is
unchecked. (in target 'decidoapp' from project 'decidoapp') warning:
Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt
Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not
specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output
dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every
build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script
phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods') warning: Run
script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right
configuration, if needed' will be run during every build because it
does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output
dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every
build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script
phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')

